# MySQL Dump - How to disable lowercase_table_names while dumping, without access to variable

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to disable this variable while dumping, without access to this variable? (For ex: AWS instance with read-only access)

There is are two tables with name `foo` and `FOO` which are creating an issue `mysqldump: Got error: 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'foo`

Comment: You have to dump the tables separately and then fix your database scheme. In general all table names should be kept lower case. Reason is that dumping mixed case names will result in huge issues on file systems that are not case sensitive like for example MS-Windows. Safest to prevent such annoying issues is to stick with the general rule above.

Comment: The upper case table was created by mistake while lowercase variable was 0. We have set the variable to 1. I am trying to delete the upper case one (FOO), but this will actually delete (foo) since the variable is 1 now!

Comment: Just temporarily rename one of the tables so you can get a dump. Handle the case issues in your imported instance that you control.

Comment: @pvg - Any idea how to rename it, coz, what I feel is, trying to rename (FOO) will actually rename (foo)

Comment: @arunwithasmile shouldn't really matter which one it renames as long as it renames one. just rename it to xxyzzy, if you have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by dumping each table individually. Weird, but helped. Thanks @arkascha for suggesting this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not finding the table names under linux mysql, coz its default is case-sensitive. And for windows its case-insensitive.

I can't guess if ignoring case sensitivity works for you. But you can do by adding a line in my.conf. i.e. making mysql in linux to be case insensitive.

```
mysqlserver:~# vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
...
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

Also as per table naming convention of mysql table name must be in lower case.

http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/mysql/w/wiki/6103.naming-conventions

Comment: It is the file systems that are case sensitive or not in different systems, not the systems themselves. Simple storage engines like MyISAM store the tables in files called alongside the table name which then leads to issues.

Comment: I do not have a my.cnf file. This is an amazon instance, and I do not have access to variables.

Comment: in amazon instance also there is my.cnf .